# Closing Accordion Re-Opens the Same Accordion Element

Tags: jquery

Just set up a simple Accordion with jQuery. The basic structure is an H3 acting as the header, with a div below acting as the container. I'm using the following code and things are working well when opening and closing elements:

```
var panels = $('#edit-options > .option-category > div.options').hide();

   $('#edit-options > .option-category > h3').click(function() {
      panels.slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideDown();
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
      return false;
   });
```

The problem happens when trying to close the same accordion; it only reopens immediately after being closed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure that we could help you if you were to recreate the problem in a jsfiddle and add a link to it in your question.

Comment: Apologies guys. I was sadly insufficient here. Please excuse the erroneous markup in the HTML. This is coming from a Drupal build. (Also, the bottom two elements will not work as I will be cleaning these up in the template files so that they live within the right areas. For now, these can be ignored).

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jOP4UlFnfB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivceedub/zAGX8/4/) shows the answer.  Please note a couple of things . . .

Your code calls `slideDown()` whenever an accordion header gets clicked.

```
$('#edit-options > .option-category > h3').click(function () {
    panels.slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    . . . .
});
```

This behavior breaks when a user clicks an open accordion header simply to hide its contents.  The below code first checks to see if the clicked-on header represents the open accordion.  If it does, then you don't want to call `slideDown()` on it.

```
$('#edit-options > .option-category > h3').click(function () {
    panels.slideUp();
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {  
        $(this).removeClass('open') // we just closed this accordion and don't need to open a new accordion tab
    } else { //we need to open a new accordion tab and mark it as the tab that is open
        $('#edit-options > .option-category > h3').removeClass('open');
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    };
    return false;
});
```

Also, your html has a bug in that it loads the Price Range header with a class of 'open'.

```
 <h3 class="open">Price Range</h3>
```

This is a mistake because on pageload no accordions are open.  The tag should simply be:

```
<h3>Price Range</h3>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer chuck. Thanks so much for both the revised fiddle and the clarification.

Comment: Glad that I could help